# accessing static files from html in db

Tags: django

I have html stored in the db which contains image tags. How can I code it so the images are pulled from the static dir?

I want the equivalent of:

```
<img src='{% static 'images/pic1' %}'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very rare that you really want to keep HTML in the database. Usually, you are better off keeping it in statically served files.

That said, just render your html with a RequestContext:

```
from django.template import Template, RequestContext

def get(self, request, *args,  **kwargs):
    ...
    html = HtmlModel.objects.get(name='unusual_practice').html
    template = Template(html)
    rendered_html = template.render(RequestContext(request))
    ...
```

RequestContext picks up the context processors, so you should have your STATIC_URL in there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm trying to create a CMS for essentially a static site. How else can I display arbitrary HTML? Would markup be better? Does markup work with images?

Comment: Good point. I should not make such blanket statements. A CMS is among very few situations where you must do that (or at least stick SOME kind of markup in there). User-entered content had not even crossed my mind, frankly.